# Limiting the size of a Map via Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(...) in Java caused collisions

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, collision

I was attempting to limit the size of a new map I was creating via Google's Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(n) method as a (minor) spatial optimization since I knew how many key-value entries it would contain.  Instead of inserting each of the new key-value pairs in it's own bucket a collision occurred and my first key-value pair was overwritten, despite the two keys being different values.  My keys were String objects and n = 3.  The two keys that hashed to the same bucket were "records" and "pageSize".

When I changed the code to simply use Maps.newHashMap() the behavior was as expected though it produced unused space within the data structure.  My guess, without diving into the actual code, is that limiting the size of the HashMap simply leads to higher probability of collisions, though I would have thought a core data structure would handle this a bit more gracefully.  So my questions are:

- Is newHashMapWithExpectedSize(n) to be avoided when using small values for n?
- After inserting "records" into the map, if I had called map.hasKey("pageSize") would I get true?

Comment: Of course it causes collisions. What else could you possibly expect?

Comment: @EJP Then what's the point of the newHashMapWithExpectedSize() if when I insert new values they will overwrite old ones?  And what would be a better solution to limiting the spatial resources of a map while still ensuring all values are written?

Comment: @mattforni: There should be no possible way one `put` can overwrite another `put` if the keys are not equal according to `Object.equals`, no matter what.  It doesn't matter how the hash map is constructed, or what size it has, and it should work even if every single key has the exact same hash code.  Please provide a test case that demonstrates the behavior so we can identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whether two keys will hash to the same bucket depends on a combination of the `hashCode()` for each and the number of buckets (plus the algorithm used to map hash codes to buckets, obviously).

It's entirely possible for two keys to hash to the same bucket for just about any table size. Collisions are natural in hash tables — the goal is just to ensure a low average number of entries in each bucket relative to the total number of entries. A larger hash table reduces the chance of collisions at the cost of more space.

> Is newHashMapWithExpectedSize(n) to be avoided when using small values for n?

No, not really. Is the fact that you have a collision actually a problem?

> After inserting "records" into the map, if I had called map.hasKey("pageSize") would I get true?

If and only if you've added an entry with the key "pageSize". Hashing to the same bucket has no effect on the behavior of the map. Multiple entries can be stored in each bucket, and only if a key that *equals* the "pageSize" parameter is found will `hasKey` return true.

> since I knew how many key-value entries it would contain

Can you use `ImmutableMap` instead? Often when you know ahead of time how many entries the map will contain, it's meant to be immutable. Since `ImmutableMap` knows that the number of entries it contains will never change, it tends to be possible for it to optimize its size better than a mutable `HashMap`. Not to mention all the other benefits of immutability.

Comment: The collision is actually a problem since I wanted key-value pairs for both "records" and "pageSize" but after inserting "pageSize" the "records" key and value were overwritten.  I can use an ImmutableMap, and I have since remedied the situation by using a HashMap without an expected size.  I was just curious why the two keys would hash to the same bucket when the map was constructed with expected size and would **not** hash to the same bucket when it wasn't.  I'm fairly certain the probability of the two strings hashing to the same value is small.

Comment: @mattforni: `HashMap`s do _not_ overwrite one key with a different key, regardless of how they're created. Period. Something else must be going on, and you'll need to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem if we're to help you figure it out.

Comment: Also, as I explained: multiple entries hashing to the same bucket is normal for hash tables. Buckets can hold multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're giving all the information here? Here's an interactive Scala session that shows what you're trying to do:

```
scala> val map = com.google.common.collect.Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize[String, String](3)
map: java.util.HashMap[String,String] = {}

scala> map.put("pageSize", "foo")
res1: String = null

scala> map.put("records", "bar")
res2: String = null

scala> map.put("third", "3")
res3: String = null

scala> map.put("fourth", "4")
res4: String = null

scala> map.toString()
res5: String = {pageSize=foo, fourth=4, records=bar, third=3}
```

As you can see, the instance returned by that method is a `java.util.HashMap`; you can add more than the number of elements you requested; and collisions are handled just fine.

In fact, if you look [at the source](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Maps.java#193), that method is just a wrapper around the HashMap constructor.